# Django Tastypie use_in with relations

Tags: django, tastypie

I have some Tastypie Resources that render something like this when called:

```
{
   "meta":{
      "limit":1,
      "next":"/api/v1/studio/?limit=1&offset=1",
      "offset":0,
      "previous":null,
      "total_count":93
   },
   "objects":[
      {
         "full_address":"1234 Main St.",
         "resource_uri":"/api/v1/studio/3/",
         "state":{
            "resource_uri":"/api/v1/state/110/",
            "state_id":110,
            "state_name":"Colorado",
            "studios":[
               "/api/v1/studio/3/",
               "/api/v1/studio/4/",
               "/api/v1/studio/5/",
               "/api/v1/studio/6/",
               "/api/v1/studio/8/",
               "/api/v1/studio/11/",
               "/api/v1/studio/12/",
               "/api/v1/studio/13/",
               "/api/v1/studio/14/",
               "/api/v1/studio/15/",
               "/api/v1/studio/1/",
               "/api/v1/studio/2/"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Can I use use_in with Tastypie to exclude related fields from the list view? I can exclude a field of the immediate resource like this:

```
exclude_this_field = fields.CharField(use_in='detail', attribute='exclude_this_field')
```

State is a ForeignKey field to Studio. How do I exclude a related resource?

```
studios = fields.Charfield(use_in='detail', attribute='state__state_id')
```

Can I make something like this work to exclude a related resource?

Comment: Related fields are not displayed by default. You need to separate field to resource in order to display it. Can you show your resources for State and Studio? That

Comment: How did u solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide ForeignKeyField in details or list override the init Function of your resource and add the use_in value after calling the object parent init. It should look like this:

```
class YourResource(ModelResource)
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call the object's parent, which will set up and populate
        # the Resource fields from the queryset provided
        super(YourResource, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Now loop through the fields of the resource, and when we
        # find the one we only want to be shown in the detail view,
        # set its use_in attr appropriately
        for field_name, field_object in self.fields.items():
            if field_name == 'yourForeignFieldName':
                field_object.use_in = 'detail'
```

I hope this helps, cheers!